# if statement return false and django redirect me

Tags: python, django

i have views.py like this:

```py
def delete(request,slug):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.user == Project.objects.filter(owner=request.user):
            return render(request,'site/delete.html')
        else:
            return redirect('project:home') 
            
    else:
        return redirect('project:home')
```

myquestion is when i open this url  (`/delete/<slug:slug>`) django redirects me.
Is my if true?

```py
if request.user == Project.objects.filter(owner=request.user):
            return render(request,'site/delete.html')
        else:
            return redirect('project:home')
```

**Note: owner must be number => owner=request.user => in my example owner was 1**
**| request.user means 1, why is myif not true?what should i do to fix it?**

Comment: can you write two prints, one  after user authentication and one inside the first else and tell me which one do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must write just like this:

```py
if request.user.id == user_id:
            return render(request,'site/delete.html')
        else:
            return redirect('project:home')
```

in def:

```py
def delete(request,slug,user_id):
```

and in urls.py:

```py
path('delete/<int:user_id>/<slug:slug>',views.delete,name='delete'),
```

have an epic day!